# Turn off suggested contacts in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I really, really don't want suggestions from my contact list to come up when I address an email.  This could sometimes result in a disaster if I were to click on one of those names by accident and send the email to the wrong person. How can I disable this feature?

Comment: Delete your contacts? To my knowledge, there is no other way.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option given to disable this feature. But you can give a suggestion that it is not need from Google suggestion page and based on the public response for this feature it might be removed in future

[google_suggestions](https://support.google.com/mail/suggestions/16932?rd=1)